# I want to implement a synonyms filter which give me a results like :

Tags: search, solr, synonym

for Example If I type "US" in search box then it must return synonyms like ["USA", "United States of America", "United Stated"] only. I do not want "United" or "States" seperately in my search results

> My Synonyms.txt File
> US => US, USA, United States, United, States

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTTiR.png)

Comment: try by having the synonyms filter at the end of your index analyzer and analyze the same using the solr admin page

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use the `SynonymFilterFactory` only at index time, not query time. Try the below field type for your field.

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField">
<analyzer type="index">
  <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="mysynonyms.txt"/>
  <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
<analyzer type="query">
  <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Note : If there is already a fieldType defined with name "text", please change the name of the above field type.